# Moving Cells in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view where the user can move and re-arrange the cells in the order that he wishes. But when he moves/ re-arranges the cells multiple times the array holding the items gets totally messed up as the order of the items is concerned, but visually everything is fine. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

    id object1 = [_items5 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    id object2 = [_items5 objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

    [_items5 replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:object2];
    [_items5 replaceObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row withObject:object1];
```

where _items5 is an NSMutableArray and initialized in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping two items instead of moving the one moved item. You want:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    id object = [_items5 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [_items5 removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [_items5 insertObject:object atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

Note: If using MRC you need to retain `object` so it isn't deallocated before it is put back in the array.